# Some strange behaviour in JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I have created simple fragment of code to demonstrate some strange stuff with JAVA.

```
public class Start extends JFrame {

    public static JFrame mainFrame; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        mainFrame = f;
        f.setSize(400, 400);

        Action btn_action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("test");
                JDialog d = new JDialog(mainFrame, "Test Dialog", true);
                d.setSize(200, 200);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JTextField text = new JTextField();
                d.add(text);
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        JButton btn = new JButton(btn_action);
        btn.setText("Click me");
        KeyStroke btnShortcut = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0);
        btn.getActionMap().put("btn_click", btn_action);
        btn.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(btnShortcut, "btn_click");
        f.add(btn);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have `JFrame` component with a `JButton` on it. `JButton` has a shortcut (keyboard number `1`).

When I press `1` on top row of keyboard, action is performing. It's creating `JDialog` in action with one component on it - `JTextField`. So about what's strange

When I press `1`, that number sometimes prints in `JTextField` area of `JDialog`. It's happening sometimes. It seems to be taken from the keyboard buffer.

How can it be cleared before `JDialog` is opening ? Or is there another solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. How to replicate it?

Comment: Okay, I see the problem you mean. I can reproduce it.

Comment: @ZerO That would be VK_NUMPAD1

Comment: @tvolf: since your JDialog is modal, it will have focus and any subsequent key press will enter the value in Jtextfiled.

Comment: @Shail016: Why is JDialog catching key presses that were sent by button at JFrame but not JDialog ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try binding to the key release event, rather than the key press event, so that the key has been definitely released by the time the dialog opens:

```
KeyStroke btnShortcut = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true);
                                                                 ^^^^
```

Comment: It's the solution! I really have not known about existence of third parameter ) Thank you very much.